# Get First word that contains numbers

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Anyone can help with how can I find the first full Word that contains numbers? I have an adress, for example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SourceString      : String;
  strArray  : TArray<string>;
  i         : Integer;
begin
  SourceString := 'Saint Steven St 6.A II.f 9';
  strArray     := SourceString.Split([' ']);

for i := 0 to Length(strArray)-1 do
  showmessage(strArray[i]);
```

end;

Result:

```
Saint
Steven
St
6.A
II.f
9
```

I want to get the first Word that contain number. In the example: '6.A'.

Anyone have an idea how?

Comment: I'm curious what would happen if it were something like `34th Street`. For that, I would work backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test if a string contains a digit by looping of the string and checking each character. For instance:

```
function ContainsDigit(const S: string): Boolean;
var 
  C: Char;
begin
  for C in S do
    if (C >= '0') and (C <= '9') then
      exit(True);
  exit(False);
end;
```

Or you might prefer to write the if statement using the record helper methods from the `System.Character` unit.

```
uses
  System.Character;

....

function ContainsDigit(const S: string): Boolean;
var 
  C: Char;
begin
  for C in S do
    if C.IsDigit then
      exit(True);
  exit(False);
end;
```

Comment: You can also use `CharInSet(c, ['0'..'9'])` function. You can use it instead of in to avoid compiler warnings you have mentioned in one of your comments.

Comment: @asd-tm I'm not keen on `CharInSet` personally. I'm not convinced that it is very efficient.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid splitting the string in words:

```
function ExtractFirstWordWithNumber(const SourceString: String): String;
var
  i,start,stop: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to Length(SourceString) do
  begin
    if TCharacter.IsDigit(SourceString[i]) then
    begin // a digit is found, now get start location of word
      start := i;
      while (start > 1) and 
        (not TCharacter.IsWhiteSpace(SourceString[start-1])) do 
        Dec(start);
      // locate stop position of word
      stop := i;
      while (stop < Length(SourceString)) and 
        (not TCharacter.IsWhiteSpace(SourceString[stop+1])) do
        Inc(stop);
      // Finally extract the word with a number
      Exit(Copy(SourceString,start,stop-start+1));
    end;
  end;
  Result := '';
end;
```

First locate a digit, then extract the word from the digit position.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Regular Expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Regular_Expressions) to accomplish this task:

```
const
  CWORDS = 'Saint Steven St 6.A II.f 9';
  CPATTERN = '([a-zA-z\.]*[0-9]+[a-zA-z\.]*)+';

var
  re: TRegEx;
  match: TMatch;

begin
  re := TRegEx.Create(CPATTERN);
  match := re.Match(CWORDS);
  while match.Success do begin
    WriteLn(match.Value);
    match := match.NextMatch;
  end;
end.
```

The above prints:

> 6.A
> 9

---

To get the very first word containing numbers, like your question requires, you may consider to add a function to your code:

```
function GetWordContainingNumber(const AValue: string): string;
const
  CPATTERN = . . .;//what the hell the pattern is
var
  re: TRegEx;
  match: TMatch;
begin
  re := TRegEx.Create(CPATTERN);
  match := re.Match(AValue);
  if match.Success then
    Result := match.Value
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

The newly added function can be called like this:

```
showmessage(GetWordContainingNumber(SourceString));
```

Comment: Isn't a regex enormous overkill here?

Comment: @David I don't think so. It's weirdest to me splitting a string then calling a procedure for each token, isnt it?

Comment: Well, except that your code doesn't do the same thing as the split. Ask youself what it does if the "words" contain characters other than `[a-zA-Z\.]`. I get your point about avoiding the call to split, but you should produce something that is semantically equivalent.

Comment: @David I added the `\.` character only because is a non-word one. Only OP knows what else can contain his string. Maybe a solution like this should be better: `([^ 0-9]*[0-9]+[^ 0-9]*)+`

Comment: Now I agree and upvote though I am still not sure if the question author needs other letters except 'a-z','A'..'Z'... Probably, he is using German alphabet with ßüöäö or cyrrilic letters etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use simething like this to know if a word contains chars '0'..'9'

```
  function DigitInWord(s: string): boolean;
  var
    ch: char;
  begin
    result := false;
    for ch :='0' to '9' do
      if Pos(s, ch) > 0 then
      begin
        result := true;
        break;
      end;
  end;
```

Comment: Using `IntToStr` is over the top here. May as well have a `char` loop variable running from `'0'` to `'9'`. However, as you have written this, it is expensive. You potentially loop over each word 10 times rather than once.

Comment: You are right, @David I have edited the post with char loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
function WordContainsNumber(const AWord: string): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to Length(AWord) do
    if CharInSet(AWord[i], ['0'..'9']) then
      Exit(true);

  Exit(false);
end;

function GetFirstWordThatContainsANumber(const AWords: TArray<string>): string;
var
  CurrentWord: string;
begin
  Result := '';

  for CurrentWord in AWords do
    if WordContainsNumber(CurrentWord) then
      Exit(CurrentWord);        
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SourceString      : String;
  strArray  : TArray<string>;
  i         : Integer;
begin
  SourceString := 'Saint Steven St 6.A II.f 9';
  strArray     := SourceString.Split([' ']);

  for i := 0 to Length(strArray)-1 do
    showmessage(strArray[i]);

  ShowMessage('The first word containing a number is ' + GetFirstWordThatContainsANumber(strArray));    
end;
```