# Determine if string not contain number

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I need a little help with a function. What I need to do is determine, if a string contains a number or not. If yes, I need only a number from the string, if not I need a whole word from it.

For example:

If my string is `'xyz 60'`, I need `'60'` from it, but if the string is `'xyz'`, I need the whole string:

```
  function TForm1.FindNumberInString(InString: string): TNumberInString;
  var
    i, j: Integer;
    ST: String;
  begin
    Result.TNumber := '';
    Result.TIsNumber := False;

    for i := 1 to Length(InString) do
    begin
      if (InString[i] in ['0'..'9']) then
      begin
        Result.TNumber := Result.TNumber + InString[i];
        Result.TIsNumber := True;
      end else 
        Result.TNumber := InString;
    end;      
  end;

 // TNumberInString is a packed record

 TNumberInString = Packed Record
   TNumber: string;
   TIsNumber: boolean;
 end;
```

Anyone can help what will be the problem? The Result is always `'xyz60'`, not `'60'`. I tried `"if not (InString[i] in...)`, but it did not work, too.

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948001/get-first-word-that-contains-numbers

Comment: `if (InString[i] in ['0'..'9'])` is very different from `if not (InString[i] in ['0'..'9'])`. Why are you trying things seemingly at random? Have you done any debugging? Have you inspected the program as it executes? What did you learn? Why are you looping from `0` to `Length`? Strings are 1-based, assuming you really are using XE. Why are you packing records? That results in misaligned data.

Comment: Having asked all those questions, my suggestion is that you back up a little, and think. What you think you need to do is make this code work. But that's missing the big picture. The big picture is that you've not yet learnt how to debug your code. Which leads to you getting very confused, and trying code at random, being frustrated and so on. Make it your goal to find out how to debug your code.

Comment: What @DavidHeffernan says.  Plus, what about when InString is, say '2A4"?  Should that return 2 or 24 for your purpose?

Comment: `0 to Length(InString)`, really?

Comment: The problem with your code is the 'else' statement. If any part of your string is not numeric Result.TNumber is set to the value of the input string. There should be no else clause there. Instead after the loop finishes test Result.TIsNumber and set Result.TNumber to the input string if it is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Regular Expressions, and extend your record with a **constructor**

```
uses
  RegularExpressions;
{$R *.dfm}

type
  TNumberInString = Packed Record
    TNumber: string;
    TIsNumber: Boolean;
    constructor Create(const Value: String);
  end;

  { TNumberInString }

constructor TNumberInString.Create(const Value: String);
var
  Match: TMatch;
begin
  Match := TRegEx.Create('\d+').Match(Value);
  TIsNumber := Match.Success;
  if TIsNumber then
    TNumber := Match.Value
  else
    TNumber := Value;
end;
```

Then only thing left is to call it:

```
procedure TForm30.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(TNumberInString.Create('XYZ').TNumber);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(TNumberInString.Create('XYZ60').TNumber);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(TNumberInString.Create('XYZ 60').TNumber);
end;
```

And show the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try something more like this instead:

```
function TForm1.FindNumberInString(InString: string): TNumberInString;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  Result.TNumber := InString;
  Result.TIsNumber := False;

  for i := 1 to Length(InString) do
  begin
    if InString[i] in ['0'..'9'] then
    begin
      Result.TNumber := InString[i];
      Result.TIsNumber := True;
      For j := i+1 to Length(InString) do
      begin
        if not (InString[i] in ['0'..'9']) then
          Break;
        Result.TNumber := Result.TNumber + InString[j];
      end;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;      
end;
```