# Else Error in program

Tags: pascal

It gives an error at the first else, saying it was not expected

Also if some one is willing to add me in Skype so I can ask these basic questions, it would help a lot.

```
Program Game ;

var answer: string;

Begin

writeln('(======= MENU =======)');
writeln('-------- PLAY --------');  
writeln('-------- HELP --------');
writeln('-------- EXIT --------');

repeat

writeln('Pick PLAY, HELP or EXIT');
readln(answer);

if answer = 'EXIT' then
      writeln();
      writeln('Write EXIT again!')
    else 
      if answer = 'HELP' then
    writeln();
    writeln('Simple commands like observe, look, take.')
      else 
    if answer = 'PLAY' then
    writeln();
            writeln('You are in a cave!');

until answer = 'EXIT';

End.
```

Comment: Please, post your code as text rather than as an image.

Comment: `basic` tag is for Beginner's All-purpose Symbolic Instruction Code... not for  "simple" questions.

Comment: The indentation of the code is messed up. I didn't fix it because it seems to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32933320/5043424). I gave an extended answer on `if then else` syntax

Comment: Thanks, I really need the basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pascal expects *one* statement between `if` and `else`. It understands your code incorrectly:

```
if answer = 'EXIT' then
    writeln(); (* one statement *)

writeln('Write EXIT again!') (* unrelated to the "if" above *)

else (* error - no preceding "if" *)
```

The solution is, use `begin` and `end` to enclose 2 statements in one:

```
if answer = 'EXIT' then
  begin
    writeln();
    writeln('Write EXIT again!')
  end
else
...
```