# Pascal error: until expected else found

Tags: syntax-error, pascal

Fatal error while trying to compile "until" expected found "else", cant seem to get how to fix it

......

```
   begin

divisor:= 2;
cont:= 0; 
write(i,':');

repeat

  if (i mod divisor = 0) then
     begin
write(' divisor ');
divisor:=succ(divisor);
cont:=succ(cont);
      end;

  else
divisor:=succ(divisor);

until (cont = 6) or (divisor>i div 2)

writeln();
    end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: If you'd properly format your code, you might have seen the error yourself. And well, error messages are usually right.

Comment: You can also read one of my old [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32933320/5043424) about alike issue.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that you have a semicolon after `end;` before `else`. That basically terminates the `if` statement so the `else` becomes an `else` to `repeat` (which obviously isn't valid). The fix is to remove the semicolon after `end;`

See this for reference: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Else

Fix:

```
  if (i mod divisor = 0) then
     begin
       write(' divisor ');
       cont:=succ(cont);
     end
  else
    divisor:=succ(divisor);
```