# can i use case inside if statement in pascal

Tags: if-statement, pascal, freepascal, case-statement

I want to using case on if statement, can I use it? Because I always got error when i compile it ;w;

Error I got:

```
Tahun.pas(26,21) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found
Tahun.pas(0) Fatal: Compilation aborted
```

Here my code:

```
uses Crt;
var
sisa, bulan, tahun : integer;

begin
ClrScr;
writeln('masukkan tahun'); read(tahun);
sisa := tahun mod 4;
if sisa =0 then
writeln('masukkan bulan 1-12'), read(bulan);
 case bulan of
  1: write('31');
  2: write('29');
  3: write('31');
  4: write('30');
  5: write('31');
  6: write('30');
  7: write('31');
  8: write('30');
  9: write('31');
  10: write('30');
  11: write('31');
  12: write('30');
  else write('bulan tidak lebih dari 12');
end;
else
writeln('masukkan bulan 1-12'), read(bulan);
 case bulan of
  1: write('31');
  2: write('28');
  3: write('31');
  4: write('30');
  5: write('31');
  6: write('30');
  7: write('31');
  8: write('30');
  9: write('31');
  10: write('30');
  11: write('31');
  12: write('30');
else write('bulan tidak lebih dari 12')
end;
 readln;
 readln;

end.
```

Or maybe you know how to improve the code? ;w;

Thank you for answering ;w;

Comment: Read about compound statements with begin / end

Comment: Thank you, i will read it now ;w;

Comment: Instead of embedding `write` statements in your `case`statements, you would do better to write a function which has input parameters which specify a month number and whether the year is a leap year and returns the number of days in the month.

Comment: Can you give me simple example about a function which has input parameters? ;w;

Comment: This is a hopeless way to learn how to program. Any decent introduction text will teach you what a function is. You've got the wrong idea of what stack overflow is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan im sorry ;w;

Comment: Oh! wait, i got it, thank you guys for answering :3

Comment: Fwiw, the calculation of a leap year is a little more complicated than "every year divisible by four".

Comment: Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32933320/5043424) there are detailed explanations  of `begin`...`end` brackets usage in `if` `then` `else` statements.

Comment: I don't see why this needs extra explanation. `if` is defined as thus: `if <condition> then <statement1> [else <statement>];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have read the links upon the pieces of advice given in the comments yesterday. So there are several possible answers to the question:

The **1st –** to repair your code:

```
begin
  writeln('masukkan tahun');
  readln(tahun);
  writeln('masukkan bulan 1-12');
  readln(bulan);
  case bulan of
    1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12: writeln('31');
    2: if tahun mod 4 = 0 then
         writeln('29')
       else
         writeln('28');
    4, 6, 9, 11: writeln('30');
  else
    write('bulan tidak lebih dari 12');
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

**2nd –** to optimize it:

```
const
  DinM: array [boolean, 1 .. 12] of byte =
  ((31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31),
   (31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31));

begin
  writeln('masukkan tahun');
  readln(tahun);
  writeln('masukkan bulan 1-12');
  readln(bulan);
  writeln(DinM[tahun mod 4 = 0, bulan]);
  readln;
end.
```

And **3rd:**

Use predesigned functions: Delphi has a function `DaysInAMonth` described [here.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.DateUtils.DaysInAMonth)
Lazarus [has it](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/rtl/dateutils/daysinamonth.html) as well.

**Note**

Remember that all these methods (including standard functions) will give an error calculating leap years as not all years that `year mod 4 = 0` are leap. For example year 1700, 1800, 1900, 2100 etc. are not leap.