# Illegal expression in Else line

Tags: if-statement, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

When I try to compilate my code a

> "unit1.pas(53,1) Error: Illegal expression"

in else line appears.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var x: real;
begin
x:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
if x>=0
then
Label1.Caption= FloatToStr(x)
else
Label1.Caption:= Floattostr(x);
```

Comment: In addition to anwer of MartynA see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32933320/5043424).

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong is the expression **before** the `else`.  You have an equals sign `=` where you ought to have an assignment operator `:=`, as you have in the `else`:

```
if x>=0 then 
  Label1.Caption := FloatToStr(x) 
else 
  Label1.Caption:= Floattostr(x);
```